# Printing number of loop in function in R

Tags: r, list, function

when I call in R

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  l[[i]] <- function(x) exp(i*x)
}
```

in each entry of the list, one can find the output

```
function(x) exp(i*x)
```

But what I want is, that I get when calling l[[1]] the output

```
function(x) exp(1*x)
```

when I call l[[2]] the output

```
function(x) exp(2*x)
```

and so on. Is there a possibility to code this in R? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this really necessary? Do you really need a function in each element of a list? Can you give us some context, why you want this?

Comment: try this:
l[[i]] <- "function(x) exp(i*x)"

Comment: @Cettt that does only create character objects, but does not what I want

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
l <- sapply(1:4, function(k) eval(str2lang(sprintf("function(x) exp(%s*x)", k))))
```

which gives

```
> l
[[1]]
function (x)
exp(1 * x)
<environment: 0x000000001fb8f348>

[[2]]
function (x)
exp(2 * x)
<environment: 0x000000001fb8c350>

[[3]]
function (x)
exp(3 * x)
<environment: 0x000000001f7c4ef8>

[[4]]
function (x)
exp(4 * x)
<environment: 0x000000001f7c5c50>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `body<-` we can avoid the use of `eval`:

**1)** Use bquote on the expression assigning it to the body of the function.

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  l[[i]] <- function(x) {}
  body(l[[i]]) <- bquote(exp(.(i)*x))
}
```

giving this list of functions:

```
> l
[[1]]
function (x) 
exp(1L * x)

[[2]]
function (x) 
exp(2L * x)

[[3]]
function (x) 
exp(3L * x)

[[4]]
function (x) 
exp(4L * x)
```

**2)** This also works:

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  l[[i]] <- function(x) {}
  body(l[[i]]) <- substitute(exp(i*x), list(i = i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substitute`:

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  l[[i]] <- substitute(function(x) exp(j*x), list(j=i))
}
l
#[[1]]
#function(x) exp(1L * x)
#
#[[2]]
#function(x) exp(2L * x)
#
#[[3]]
#function(x) exp(3L * x)
#
#[[4]]
#function(x) exp(4L * x)
```

In case you also want to use it for calculations you either make:

```
eval(l[[2]])(3)
#[1] 403.4288
```

or you make `eval` already in the loop:

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  l[[i]] <- eval(parse(text=deparse(substitute(function(x) exp(j*x), list(j=i)))))
}

l[[2]]
#function(x) exp(2L * x)

l[[2]](3)
#[1] 403.4288
```